# Wordpress preview URL of Draft or pending post

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

i have a problem with the preview link, generated for a post with the post-status "draft". I guess "pending" is the same.
There is a permastructure defined like this:

```
add_permastruct('post-type-name', '/page-name/%post-type-name%', array(
    'with_front' => false,
    'walk_dirs' => false
));
```

When i click on Preview for a post with post status "published" it redirects to http://domain-name.dev/wordpress/page-name/post-type-name/. That's fine.

When i click on Preview for a post with post status "draft" it redirects to http://domain-name.dev/wordpress/?p=12345&post_type=post-type-name&preview_id=12345&preview=true&preview_nonce=123nonce45. Permastructure is not applied.

WordPress Version 4. Installed in a sub directory called "wordpress".

htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any Ideas?

Also tested with a fresh WP 4 installation in root folder, without any plugins or custom post-types. Quite the same.

Thanks for helping me out.
Cheers from Berlin
christoph

Comment: I think this is not bug - this is feature :) Wordpress just not generate and save permalinks for non-published posts.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But there are situations where you need it. In my case it's because showing draft previews in regular page layout.

Comment: Solution in my case was to add page-id (depending on post-type of previewed post) to the preview link as a parameter for routing.

Answer (score 0):

Those who still having this problem.

I had this problem but it derived by my custom rewrite_rule.
I have solved it by modifying the get_preview_post_link args

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'custom_preview_post_link', 10, 2 );

function custom_preview_post_link( $link, \WP_Post $post )
{
//    if ($post->post_status != 'publish') {
         return remove_query_arg( 'preview_id', $link );
//    }
};
```

NOTE: I have added a condition to check the post_status != 'publish' inside the function alter_normal_post_link() and it will be called here add_filter('post_link', 'alter_normal_post_link', 10, 3);

This may not answer your problem but just give you an idea.